# Inconsistent swapping in python

Tags: python-3.x

I can't understand why python swapping is working differently in the following example. Could someone please explain? I'm using python 3.6.9.

```
i = 0
perm = [2, 0, 1, 3]
perm[i], perm[perm[i]] = perm[perm[i]], perm[i]
print(perm)
[1, 2, 1, 3]

perm = [2, 0, 1, 3]
perm[perm[i]], perm[i] = perm[i], perm[perm[i]]
print(perm)
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understand Python swapping: why is a, b = b, a not always equivalent to b, a = a, b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152730/understand-python-swapping-why-is-a-b-b-a-not-always-equivalent-to-b-a-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, a,b = b,a means
t = a; a = b; b = t;
sequentially. In the second case, it exchange the values at index 0 and index 2.
In the first case, after assigning the value to perm[i], perm[i] became 1, so the next step become to assign value at index 0 to index 1.